# How to make promoted widgets show up larger in Qt Designer

Tags: python, layout, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am working on an app which has a number of promoted widgets. My work flow is as follows:

1. Design a new widget with buttons, labels, textedits etc. in Qt Designer, save a .ui file `new_widget.ui`.
2. I am working in Python with PyQt5 so I use PyQt5 to convert this .ui file into a .py file `new_widget_ui.py`.
3. I then make a new file `new_widget.py` which defines a class `NewWidget` which inherits from the ui class which is defined in `new_widget_ui.py` and calls `SetupUi()`. Additionally signal slot functionality etc. is defined in `NewWidget` class.
4. I want this new widget to appear as a subwidget in my mainwindow so in `app_window.ui` in Qt Designer I place a generic widget and promote it to class `NewWidget` from header file `new_widget.py`.

All of the above works perfectly, I've done it for many widgets with nestings etc. The problem I have is cosmetic/convenience.

The app is to control and visualize the data collected by a camera. There is a main widget `display_widget` which displays the camera output. This widget should be as large as possible given the window size so it has an expanding size policy. All of the other widgets are adjusting settings for this camera so they should be as small as possible to not shrink the main display.

So I've given the main display an expanding size policy and stretch factors of 1 while the other widgets typically have preferred size policies (defined both in the `new_widget.ui` file and as the properties of the new_widget placeholder in `app_window.ui`) so that they will shrink in favor of the expansion of the `display_widget`. I also use spacers to compress the options widgets as much as possible.

All of this works basically as desired when I run the program. The problem is that in Qt Designer all of the widgets shrink to basically zero size (as expected). This makes it unfortunately difficult to develop the Ui since I can't click on the widgets that I want to and it's hard to add new widgets to the appropriate layouts.

My workaround is to set minimum sizes to 50 or 100 for all of the subwidgets so that I can get a rough idea for how the layout will actually look while I'm developing the ui. However, I have to make sure to set all of these minimum sizes back to zero when I finish and I'm ready to run the app again because if I don't it ruins the actual behavior.

## Question:

Is there a better way to have promoted placeholder widgets have a non-zero size in Qt Designer so you can easily see where they are and add new widgets to layouts?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

### Premise

There is no simple solution for this.

If those widgets are pretty complex and you're going to have many of them in your GUI, a possibility is to create your own widget plugin, but that's *not* easy, as the docs are all C++ oriented, and the rare available documentation for PyQt is very old and fragmentary (also, some functions in the plugin dedicated classes are not even implemented in PyQt).

It *is* doable, but it's not easy nor painless. You can start by reading a [**very old** tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq26-pyqtdesigner.html) (it's dated back to 2008!), and there are some questions even here on SO that can help you. It takes a lot of time to understand how it works and how to implement it, but if your UI is complex it *might* be worth it.

### A (dirty) workaround

Whenever a widget is loaded from uic or a pyuic file, `setMinimumSize()` is explicitly called even if only one size direction is set as a minimum size.

As long as you are fine with not setting the *actual* minimum size for the promoted widget in Designer (at least, not using the dedicated fields; I'll explain more about this on the next point), the (very, *very*, **very** dirty) workaround is to override `setMinimumSize()` and, eventually, restore the default base implementation right after the UI is loaded, so that you can actually set the minimum size if you need to do that programmatically.

In this way, even if a minimum size is set on the UI, `setupUi()` (or `loadUi()` if you're using `uic`) will not be able to set it since the base implementation method is *not* going to be called.

**Note**: Remember that if you want a default minimum size for a widget *class*, you should use [`minimumSizeHint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#minimumSizeHint-prop), and not `setMinimumSize()`. Overriding the minimum size hint for the class ensures that all new instances will always have a minimum size for the layout, while you can still set your own minimum size for any widget you want.

This is an example of the promoted class definition:

```
class Promoted(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # create a reference to the default implementation
        self.__setMinimumSize = self.setMinimumSize
        self.setMinimumSize = self.ignoredSetMinimumSize
        # ...

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        # a default minimum size *hint* for the layout, whenever this widget will 
        # be added to a layout, it will *never* make it smaller than this size; 
        # this is obviously an arbitrary size
        return QtCore.QSize(15, 15)

    def ignoredSetMinimumSize(self, minSize):
        # ignoring calls to setMinimumSize
        return

    def restoreSetMinimumSize(self):
        # restore the original base implementation
        self.setMinimumSize = self.__setMinimumSize
```

Then, on the window that is going to use the ui (or pyuic) file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from promoted import Promoted


class Win(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('test.ui', self)
        for widget in self.findChildren(Promoted):
            widget.restoreSetMinimumSize()
        # an example to show that the original implementation is actually restored
        self.promotedWidget.setMinimumSize(50, 50)
```

### How to actually set a minimum size

As said, this has an important drawback: if you *do* need to set a minimum size for any of those custom widgets in Designer, you obviously cannot do that from the normal minimum size fields on the property editor.

The solution is to use a dynamic property with a custom method for that.

In the property editor, create a new property (for example, `customMinimumHeight`) by clicking on the "+ [Add Dynamic Property]" button on top of the property panel, and set it to the actual required amount, then override the [`event()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event) method and check for `QtCore.QEvent.DynamicPropertyChange` event types within an `event()` override.

Note that you have to select the correct property type from the menu, then type in the property name.
Select `Int` from the combo box if you're going to change only one size direction, otherwise you can set both width and height using the `Size` type. Note that if you're going to set only a size direction, you must also ensure that the opposite side is not already set: in that case the opposite direction must be set to the maximum possible amount (16777215).

Remember also that the minimum and maximum sizes are set to invalid values (-1) only *internally*: on the "public" side, they will always be equal to 0 if they have explicitly been set to 0 or not set at all. This means that you have to be very careful if, for any reason, you're going to explicitly set the minimum or maximum height/width to 0. While this is usually not a problem for the maximum size, it *might* be whenever the minimumSizeHint is set.

```
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.DynamicPropertyChange:
            if event.propertyName() == 'customMinimumHeight':
                width = self.minimumWidth() or 16777215
                height = self.property('customMinimumHeight')
                self.__setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(width, height))
            elif event.propertyName() == 'customMinimumWidth':
                width = self.property('customMinimumWidth')
                height = self.minimumHeight() or 16777215
                self.__setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(width, height))
            elif event.propertyName() == 'customMinimumSize':
                self.__setMinimumSize(self.property('customMinimumSize'))
        return super().event(event)
```